# Easiest way to flip dates between US and Uk

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor Server app, its users are based both the UK and US.  Is there an easy way to flip the date to the appropriate MMM  `dd yy (for US)` and `dd MMM yy (for UK) users`.  I have various date fields dotted around in pages/components/grids in my app:

```
@(data?.End_Date?.ToString("dd MMM yy"))
```

If there a simple way I can put the date n an IF statement to check if the user browser culture is UK or US?

Or is there another way I should be doing this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IFormatProvider` overload for `ToString`.

This outputs the date in `US` format:

```cs
date.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat);
```

This outputs the date in `GB` format:

```cs
date.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat);
```